# Object.keys = for Loop

Tags: javascript

I am building a dynamic table that uses localstorage to output the table, i have found some code online and im now trying too figure out each line

I have a hard time describing this piece of code, my main problem is understanding what the Object.key method is doing ( what effekt i has on the table), is it just a other form oof looping? Also i have a hard time figuring out what the data.foreach(function (object) line does for the table.

```
//Employee Database "Localstorage"
if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
    var employeeList = [];
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "SM1@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "MS@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", "Female", "Sales",1998, "JT@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", "Male","IT", 1997, "BN@cbs.dk"));

    var employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList);
    localStorage.setItem("Employee", employeeListString);
    document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
} else {
    var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
}

function buildTable(data) {
    // creates variable "table"
    let table = document.createElement("table");

        // Create table head and body
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));

        let fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
        let headRow = document.createElement("tr");
        fields.forEach(function (field) {
            let headCell = document.createElement("th");
            headCell.textContent = field;
            headRow.appendChild(headCell);
        });
        table.querySelector("thead").appendChild(headRow);
        data.forEach(function (object) {
            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            fields.forEach(function (field) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.textContent = object[field];
                if (typeof object[field] == "number") {
                    cell.style.textAlign = "left";
                }
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
            table.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(row);
        });
        return table;

    }

document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
```

Comment: where is declaration of `data` variable?

Comment: [MDN documentation of `Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Ah yes, the data is a array of Employees (objects)

Comment: Sorry, i edited the code in now

Comment: You need to study Javascript basic - intermediate concepts to understand this if you don't already.  However you have learned so far seems to have led you astray and taught you only specific things and not core fundamentals.  MDN (as mentioned in the answer and other comments) is a good start but what you should be doing is trying things and researching as you try to learn exactly what to do

Answer (score 1):

There's a wealth of information available on the MDN website where you can find answers to questions like these; I highly recommend using it.

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element.

So yes, it is a different way of looping. [Much](https://davidtang.io/2016/07/30/javascript-for-loop-vs-array-foreach.html) [has](https://alligator.io/js/foreach-vs-for-loops/) [been](https://thecodebarbarian.com/for-vs-for-each-vs-for-in-vs-for-of-in-javascript.html) [written](https://www.google.com/search?q=array+foreach+vs+for+loop&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS862US862&oq=array+foreach+vs+&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l6.5216j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about the differences between them and when you might choose one over the other, and they've done a far better job than I can; TL;DR and way oversimplifying, it's readability and style vs performance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data[0] contains an object like

```js
const myDataAt0 = {
  x:5,
  y:10
};

console.log(Object.keys(myDataAt0));

myDataAt0['z'] = 15

console.log(Object.keys(myDataAt0));
```

the first console.log expression will give you the two keys x and y

the second will include z, this is because all javascript properties are, simplified i admit, all just name / value pairs.